# Is there algebraic content to the clutching construction on a sphere?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

I understand the following: one can classify rank 2 vector bundles over $S^2$ by considering two open sets, say slightly extending northern and southern hemispheres. These are contractible, cover $S^2$, and their intersection is $S^1$. Any vector bundle is trivial when restricted to the open sets, so we care only about gluing two trivial bundles on $S^1$, with structure group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. we care about functions $f:S^1\to GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. I also understand that homotopic maps will induce the same bundle, so what we really need is $\pi_1(GL_2(\mathbb{R}))$, which I'm told is $\mathbb{Z}$.

My question is, does the group structure of $\mathbb{Z}$ mean anything in terms of the vector bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of course yes.

For example, there is a distinguished element $0\in \mathbb{Z}$, which corresponds to trivial bundle over $S^2$. Similarly the negation $n\mapsto -n$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to reversing the orientation of the vector bundle.

The addition is slightly more complicated to give a simple geometric meaning, but the point is that the Euler class gives an explicit bijection between the (K-theoretic) set of rank 2 vector bundles over $S^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

Edit: By the by, I didn't really explain why the Euler class $\in H^2(S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ can be identified with the same number $\in \pi_1(GL_2(\mathbb{R}))(\cong \pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\times)\cong \mathbb{Z})$. For this, the best way is to introduce the first Chern class $c_1$(which is equal to the Euler class) and appeal to the fact that the first Chern class map is an isomorphism from the "group" of complex line bundles (=oriented real vector bundles of rank 2) over $S^2$ with the tensor product to $H^2(S^2)$, as is the clutching function construction.

Comment: Can you give an explicit meaning to e.g. $TS^2$?

Comment: As in, clearly it's nontrivial, so is it a generator? If not, what is the meaning of the n-th root of $TS^2$?

Comment: @Ryan it has something to answer the question of "what is so special about $TS^2$ among the vector bundles over $S^2$", which is not so clear in the context of algebraic topology considering that the tangent bundle is not given for free to any topological space. It directly refers the smooth(manifold) structure over $S^2$. At any rate, a quick answer is that the Euler class of a vector bundle (which is an element of $H^2(S^2)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$) determines the vector bundle (up to iso), and $TS^2$ has Euler class $2\in \mathbb{Z}$ (equivalently, $\chi(S^2)=2$), so it is twice the generator.

Comment: @Ryan And the canonical generator $1\in \mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to the canonical (complex) line bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1\cong S^2$. All of these discussions can be found in detail in e.g) Hatcher's VBKT or Milnor-Stasheff's Characteristic classes.